# What should be the value for CN in vendor provided SSL certificate?

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, keystore, truststore

actually i have the entries in truststore.jks like :

Owner: CN=ABC XYZ, O=ABC, C=IN

Issuer: CN=ABC XYZ, O=ABC, C=IN

and when i tried to connect using java code by configuring that jks i'm getting the following exception :

java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: IBMJSSE2, class: com.ibm.jsse2.aj)

Does anybody have any idea ideally what should be the entries for CN in both self signed and vendor provided certificate?

Is it mandatory to mention the host/domain name for CN like *.domain.com or host.domian.com?

What should be the significance of CN? Please describe in details

Comment: Error `NoSuchAlgorithmException` has nothing to do with the CN. It is about the encryption algorithms of the SSL connection. Are you running on the latest version of Java?

Comment: @Andreas: actually this looks to me more like a missing or wrong SSLContext type -- or possibly a KeyStore type, which would make some sense in relation to configuring or altering a truststore, although I concur it has nothing to do with the cert as such.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is mandatory that CN should match with the domain name of Server.

Please go through this [link](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-common-name/) for detailed explanantion.

Comment: Why should the CN match the *host name* of ISSUER, i.e. the CA (Certificate Authority)? The *server certificate* should match the domain name of the server you're connecting to.

Comment: (@Andreas+) _SSL/TLS server_ cert should have CN=domainname -- although since before 2010 it should also have SAN containing the domainname _or names plural_ in which case CN no longer matters (as your own link says). But if peer is using a private or otherwise nonstandard CA to issue working certs, your truststore should have the CA cert, which does _not_ need any particular format CN.